# Count lines of code (LOC) for JAR and AAR

Tags: android, count, dex, lines-of-code

How do we count the number of lines of code in a Library file.

For eg, a Jar or AAR.

Note - [CLOC](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) is an awesome tool, but unfortunately, it doesn't process ".class" files.

Converting JAR -> DEX and decompile DEX -> code, is one way of doing it, but the precision could be lost during the conversion and decompilation.

Comment: "How do we count the number of lines of code in a Library file" -- you don't. That is a meaningless concept. "Converting JAR -> DEX and decompile DEX -> code, is one way of doing it, but the precision could be lost during the conversion and decompilation" -- then force the developers of the library, at gunpoint, to hand over the source code to the library. Note that this may be illegal in some jurisdictions. Counting lines of source code is only possible when you have source code. Other metrics -- class counts, method counts, etc. -- can be performed on compiled Java/DEX bytecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, you might be able to get a rough idea idea of the number of lines, using the debug information in the dex file.

Using dexlib2, you could do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile(args[0], 15);

    long lineCount = 0;

    for (ClassDef classDef: dexFile.getClasses()) {
        for (Method method: classDef.getMethods()) {
            MethodImplementation impl = method.getImplementation();
            if (impl != null) {
                for (DebugItem debugItem: impl.getDebugItems()) {
                    if (debugItem.getDebugItemType() == DebugItemType.LINE_NUMBER) {
                        lineCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("%d lines", lineCount));
}
```

An alternative metric for comparing code size might be the number of instructions in a dex file. e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DexFile dexFile = DexFileFactory.loadDexFile(args[0], 15);

    long instructionCount = 0;

    for (ClassDef classDef: dexFile.getClasses()) {
        for (Method method: classDef.getMethods()) {
            MethodImplementation impl = method.getImplementation();
            if (impl != null) {
                for (Instruction instruction: impl.getInstructions()) {
                    instructionCount++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("%d instructions", instructionCount));
}
```